# (Beginner Here) How to Bevel All Curves At Once

Tags: modeling, add-on

[image: Screenshot of Imported G-Code File, Attempting to Bevel]
[image: An example spline Beveled (1000 more to go)]

I am a new Blender user attempting to animate CAD files 3D printing. I have managed to import G-Code into Blender using an Add-In, but they come in as curves without volume and I need to make them look like 3D printed filament. To do this, I would like to bevel all the curves at once, but it does not appear to be as easy as "A" -> increase depth. How do I make all the splines beveled so the object appears 3D printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have all curves selected, click on value that you want to copy and from context menu select *Copy to selected*

[image]